# Under a standard user account, after Big Sur update, why does Disk Utility continuously ask for admin authentication?

Tags: disk-utility, user-account, administrator, authentication

I'm running MacOS *Big Sur* (11.2.1) on a MacBook Air 2014.  I exclusively use the MacBook under a standard user account, though I also possess the admin credentials.

Since a recent update (I want to say it was the major update from *Catalina* 10.15, but it might have been after a minor update to 11.1 or 11.2 - both of which I was hoping would fix the issue), **Disk Utility** persistently asks me for my admin credentials whenever I open it, and *immediately upon launching*.

If I supply the correct admin credentials (and I am sure they are the correct credentials because I use them regularly without issue for routine maintenance and configuration tasks), the authentication prompt window just returns again, *ad nauseum* (with window title `Disk Utility wants to make changes.`)

If I supply the correct admin credentials, the authentication prompt window just returns again, *ad nauseum*.  I am sure they are the correct credentials because I use them regularly without issue for routine maintenance and configuration tasks.  Furthermore, an incorrect credential input has a distinctive behavior - the prompt window will shake to indicate the credentials are wrong.  This is not occuring.

The only way I can break the loop to actually access **Disk Utility** is by hitting `Cancel` on the authentication prompt window.  Sometimes I have to hit `Cancel` on several windows before the prompt "gives up".  I'd say this works about 50% of the time and I can then use **Disk Utility** as normal.  The other half of the time, `Cancel` just brings up another authentication prompt, with no way to exit the loop.  In that case, I'll just Force Close **Disk Utility** and try again.

This is a brand new behavior that I've never experienced with MacOS before, and I've been using this install continuously since *Mountain Lion*.  I'm not experiencing any similar behavior with any other MacOS modules - only with **Disk Utility**.

Any ideas how to go about troubleshooting this?

**Edit**: Out of desperation, I tried entering my credentials multiple times, just to see what would happen.  My findings are that sometimes after 5 to 10 consecutive authentications, I can get the authentication prompt to stay away - for about a minute or two.  Then it comes back again.

Similarly, after something more crazy like 50 consecutive successful authentications, I thought I had actually fixed the problem because the prompt stayed away for more than 5 minutes.  But, alas, it returned.

It seems like there is some background process that repeatedly runs when **Disk Utility** is open, which runs into an authentication problem.  These processes keep "piling up", so to speak, as long as the utility is running.  If I can clear enough of them fast enough, I can get some peace, until the next instance spins up.  I still have no clue what or why this process is not correctly authenticating in the first place.

Comment: Why does Disk Utility start automatically at all?

Comment: @nohillside I think that is the question the OP is really asking. How to find out why Disk Utility is running at login

Comment: No, I never said **Disk Utility** is starting automatically or running at login.  This problem occurs whenever I choose to open **Disk Utility**.  I assume you are misinterpreting "immediately upon launching", but this is referring to launching **Disk Utility** itself.  I've never seen "launch" used as a synonym for "boot" or "login" - only in reference to "launching an application", so I don't think my language is incorrect.

Comment: Is does sound like a bug, but what's triggering it is unclear. Do you have external disks or volumes that use FileVault? Or disk images listed in DU's sidebar?  (For more background: why do you regularly launch Disk Utility?)

Comment: I don't use FileVault at all.  I'm not sure that I "regularly" use Disk Utility, but I do often enough I guess.  The most common use case is to quickly check/verify the file system type of an external storage device.

Comment: I'm now running Big Sur 11.6.1 and the problem is now worse than ever.  The pop up now appears constantly even though I'm not using **Disk Utility** at all.  :-(